# What is the output on ubuntu terminal with smal box of zeros and one?

Tags: c, arrays, string, ubuntu, getchar

Here is my code in c.
I compiled and run it on ubuntu terminal and the maximum length(max) is printed out but not the string(longest) - it just outputs a small box with zero and one.
I am a beginner in programming.
Thank you

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int my_getline(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

main() {
    int len;
    int max;
    char line[MAXLINE];
    char longest[MAXLINE];

    max = 0;
    while ((len = my_getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
    }

    if (max > 0)
        printf("%d\t %s \n",max, longest);

    return 0;
}

int my_getline(char s[], int lim) {
    int c, i;

    for (i = 0; i < lim -1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i) {
        s[i] = c;
    }

    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }

    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

void copy(char to[], char from []) {
    int i;
    i = 0;
    while ((to[i] == from [i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `copy` routine doesn't copy anything. Probably you mean to use `=` instead of `==`.

To my taste these ideas of using assignments inside control expressions is a really bad habit that buys you nothing but trouble. Something like

```
for(;;) {
   to[i] = from[i];
   if (to[i]) ++i;
   else break;
}
```

would be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-implement your copy routine as it is not getting anything. A simple solution is as following:

```
strcpy(to, from);
```

You need to include string.h and call this instead of your copy function. If you want to implement sting copy yourself, use the following:

```
void copy(char * to, char * from) {
    int i = 0;
    while (from[i] != '\0') {
        to[i] = from[i];
        i++;
    }

    to[i] = '\0';
}
```

You need to be sure that string to is at least the same size of string from.

Comment: `to[i + 1] = '\0';` is wrong, this writes one position past where it is supposed to. This will copy every characters from `from`, leave a hole in the end, and insert `'\0'` after that. `to[i] = '\0';` is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your copy routine, you want assignment, not comparison:

```
void copy(char to[], char from []) {
    int i;
    i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from [i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
```